# Xamarin обнажурить другие запущенные приложения

Tags: android, xamarin

Нашел статью, котрая мне нужна, хотел бы узнать как такое возможно сделать в Xamarin Forms

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652076/detect-if-another-app-is-running

Answer (score 0):

грубо говоря, тупо меняете маленькие буквы на заглавные, UPPER_CASE на CamelCase и вуаля.
вызывать из контекста (приложеие или сервис). [раз](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getsystemservice?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) [два](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.activityservice?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) [три](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activitymanager.getrunningtasks?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9). и так почти везде в xamarin <-> java